# running bash command from python3

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to remove some file (from my linux machine), except few:

```
touch INCAR KPOINTS foo bar
$ls
bar  foo  INCAR  KPOINTS
$python3 mini.py
Job Done
$ls
bar  foo  INCAR  KPOINTS
```

The `mini.py` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['rm', '-f', '!(INCAR|KPOINTS|PO*|*.sh)'])
print("Job Done")
```

As can be seen in the output of `mini.py`, its notgiving any error but neither its doing its job.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `rm` is not a executable, it's just a internal command of bash. Try `run['bash', '-c', " rm ..."]`

Comment: thats not working either

Comment: `rm` is an executable in any sane system. It is part of the GNU Coreutils package and you can find it in `/bin/` or `/usr/bin` depending on your distro.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. But why don't you use `os.remove()`. It seems that the `rm` runs but cannot delete some of those files.

Comment: can I select which files NOT to dellete with `os.remove`? I mean `!(...)` part?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because [`!()`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) is an extended matching pattern, and needs to be enabled explicitly:

```
subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-O', 'extglob', '-c', 'rm -f !(INCAR|KPOINTS|PO*|*.sh)'])
```

Note this will remove the script itself...

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
import os
os.system('rm -f !(INCAR|KPOINTS|PO*|*.sh)')
```